# how to write a join condition in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

what I'm trying to do is to write something like the next query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN CustomerAccounts ca
    ON ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    AND c.State = 'NY'
```

Notice that I'm not using any WHERE clause, but I need to my JOIN have a condition. I cannot make it work in Ruby on Rails.

Can you help me out?

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 3):

You can join the tables with `LEFT JOIN`. Just pass the join condition in `joins` and you will get the expected result

```
Customer.joins("LEFT JOIN CustomerAccounts
                ON CustomerAccounts.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
                AND Customers.State = 'NY'")

#=> SELECT * FROM Customers LEFT JOIN CustomerAccounts ON CustomerAccounts.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID AND Customers.State = 'NY'
```

> Note: just `.joins()` does `INNER JOIN` so you need to specify the join with condition

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL code, translated to activerecord, would look as follows (using [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins)):

```
Customer.where(state: 'NY').joins(:customer_accounts)
```

The code assumes, you have the association set up:

```
class Customer
  has_many :customer_accounts
end
```

Comment: This would perform an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN` - it might not be exactly the same query.

Comment: @eugen, yea, [now available](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-left_outer_joins) along with `joins` and `includes` :)

Comment: This doesn't put a condition on the join, it just adds a where clause. The author is specifically looking for a way to put a condition on a join without using where.